# Cleveref - Conditional label formats

Tags: conditionals, cleveref, ref

I am trying to define a new reference style with `cleveref`:

```latex
\crefname{prop}{property}{properties}
\creflabelformat{prop}{#2#1.\@#3}
```

This is meant to be used in a list of numbered properties in an enumerate environment.
Labels should render as "property 1.", and "properties 1. to 4." for a range.

It works as intended, but I want to deal with cases where a certain punctuation mark (in normal text) follows the \cref command.
For example, `\cref{my:label},` should render as "property 1," and not as "property 1.,".

I tried to use @ifnextchar in the label definition but (I guess due to how cleveref parses the command) the token following \cref is not the one that gets fed into @ifnextchar.

Is it possible to define a label format conditioned by which character follows the \cref command?

EDIT: Added MWE (slightly different example)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\crefname{prop}{property}{properties}
\creflabelformat{prop}{#2#1#3\@ifnextchar.{}{.\@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label[prop]{my:firstlabel}
        First property of the list

        \item \label[prop]{my:secondlabel}
        Second property of the list
    \end{enumerate}

    We will discuss the implications of \cref{my:firstlabel} and we will
    follow with \cref{my:secondlabel}.
\end{document}
```

The intended result would be "We will discuss the implications of property 1. and we will follow with property 2.", but the last period is actually printed twice (`\@ifnextchar` is not triggered).

I get the same behavior if I modify the standard `enumi` label format instead of specifying a new one, or if I use another environment (e.g. equation)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think this is more of a configuration problem of  the ` enumerate` environment. Could you post a minimal compilable code?

Comment: Thanks! I added a MWE, I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code, `\@ifnextchar` will *never* see a period. If I change the definition to

```
\creflabelformat{prop}{#2#1#3\@ifnextchar.{}{\show\@let@token.\@}}
```

TeX will show in both cases

```
> \@let@token=\fi.
\reserved@c ->\show \@let@token 
                                .\@
```

When the replacement text deriving from `\creflabelformat` is used, LaTeX is in the middle of a long processing. However you're lucky! Everything is performed in a single group, so we can solve the problem with `\aftergroup` that pushes a token to be executed when the current group ends.

In order to avoid `\@ifnextchar` gobbling spaces, a lower level technique has to be used.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\crefname{prop}{property}{properties}
\creflabelformat{prop}{#2#1#3\aftergroup\possible@period}
\newcommand{\possible@period}{\futurelet\@let@token\perhaps@add@period}
\newcommand\perhaps@add@period{\ifx\@let@token.\else.\@\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label[prop]{my:firstlabel}
   First property of the list

\item \label[prop]{my:secondlabel}
   Second property of the list
\end{enumerate}

We will discuss the implications of \cref{my:firstlabel}
and we will follow with \cref{my:secondlabel}. Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's shorter with `expl3`, but the technique is the same.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref,expl3}

\crefname{prop}{property}{properties}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \olivo_period:w
 {
  \peek_charcode:NF { . } { .\@ }
 }
\creflabelformat{prop}{#2#1#3\group_insert_after:N \olivo_period:w}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label[prop]{my:firstlabel}
   First property of the list

\item \label[prop]{my:secondlabel}
   Second property of the list
\end{enumerate}

We will discuss the implications of \cref{my:firstlabel}
and we will follow with \cref{my:secondlabel}. Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! the first solution works perfectly, and I can even chain more \ifx for catching multiple punctuation symbols.

Comment: unfortunately it breaks with ranges and multiple references. `\cref{my:firstlabel,my:secondlabel}.` is rendered as `property 1 and 2..` instead of `properties 1. and 2.` (and analogously for ranges).
I can fix the range behavior overriding it with `\crefrangelabelformat` but it seems there is no equivalent `\crefmultilabelformat`.

Comment: @AndreaOlivo That was something I feared. As I said, the command `\cref` does *many* things after processing the replacement text in `\creflabelformat`, so when the `\@ifnextchar` will happen to be evaluated is quite unpredictable.

Comment: It's OK, I'm starting to think that my style is not even typographically clear. I'll use a combination of normal refs and manual punctuation. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @AndreaOlivo Actually I hate those styles such as “1)”, “a)” or “1.” I know they're used, but can't stand them: a period means period and an closed parenthesis requires an open one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `enumitem`, which defines the `ref=...` key. I added the possibility to define a new list type, based on `enumerate`, which you can completely customise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\crefname{prop}{property}{properties}
\newlist{Prop}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Prop]{label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*}
\crefname{Prop}{property}{properties}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[ref=\arabic*]
        \item \label[prop]{my:firstlabel}
        First property of the list

        \item \label[prop]{my:secondlabel}
        Second property of the list
    \end{enumerate}

    We will discuss the implications of \cref{my:firstlabel} and we will
    follow with \cref{my:secondlabel}.\bigskip

    \begin{Prop}[start=3]
        \item \label[Prop]{My:firstlabel}
        First property of this list

        \item \label[Prop]{My:secondlabel}
        Second property of this list
    \end{Prop}
    We will now discuss the implications of \cref{My:firstlabel} and we will
    follow with \cref{My:secondlabel}.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think my question was confusing. Cleveref works as intended and already provides the functionality you implemented with enumitem. What I want to achieve is a way to print labels conditioned on what punctuation mark follows the \cref{} command, so that (for example) properties are printed in text as "property 1." (with a period) but not as "property 1.," if a comma follows the cref command.